# he took that chance "by himself" or "for himself"?

Tags: prepositions, word-request

Here is a sentence, in which I am trying to describe a very polite and mild personality. I am not sure if in this case I should say "take that chance for himself", "take that chance by himself" or just simply "take that chance himself".

> He is a very polite boy who never dares to interrupt anyone and would
> always give someone a chance to say something before **taking that
> chance for himself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taking a chance *by* himself** means he is alone when he takes the chance; only he is the one taking it. This is not what you mean to say.

**Taking a chance *for* himself** means he is taking the chance for his own benefit, not for anyone else's benefit. This is close to what you mean.

**Taking a chance himself** is a distinguisher meaning he is the one taking the chance, not someone else. This is the meaning you intend when you say "he would always give someone a chance to say something before taking that chance for himself."

In this context I might use "for himself" rather than just "himself" on its own. It is not strictly necessary but it adds emphasis. Similarly, using "someone *else*" instead of just "someone" emphasizes that he will not put himself forward at another's expense.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!